How to ssh from Docker container?
I am trying to dockerize a network automation tool that I built. The tool uses netmiko and paramiko to first ssh into a proxy and then ssh into a switch. With my current setup, ssh fails in the container and I believe it is because I need to mount the ssh keys into the container. Alternatively, I might need to change how I am making my ssh connection in the code to indicate the port that is forwarded on the container. What is the best way to do this while maintaining security?
I am relatively new to Docker so I do not know all of the niche quirks of Docker and I apologize if this is a basic question.
Here is my current Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /NSTConnection

COPY . /NSTConnection

COPY .venv /NSTConnection/.venv

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client

EXPOSE 22

I build the image with this command:
docker build --no-cache --network=host -t nstconn .
I run the image with this command:
docker run -it nstconn /bin/bash

Does Using SSH keys inside docker container have an answer for you?  Many of its answers focus around injecting an ssh key at build time (for example, to access a remote git repository) but there are a couple of mentions of how to do it for a running container.  You do not need to tell Docker at all that you're going to make an outbound connection (and you should delete that EXPOSE line).

What files are contained inside .? We would need some information about what files you are copying to the container. When your container is running, assuming it remains running, try docker exec -it <name> bash to start a bash session inside your container. From there you can inspect which files are present. If your container is automatically shutting itself down, then unfortunately I don't know how you can inspect its contents. There may be a way but I don't know it.
